# How can we estimate “overhead” of a compressed file?

Tags: zip, compression, overhead, overhead-minimization

Suppose we compress for example a **.txt** file that has **7** bytes size. After compression and convert to **.zip** file, the size will be **190** bytes.

Is there a way to estimate or compute the approximate size of “overhead”?

What factor affects the overhead size?

The [Zlib](http://www.zlib.net/zlib_tech.html) compute the overhead: They said: “... only expansion is an overhead of five bytes per 16 KB block (about 0.03%), plus a one-time overhead of six bytes for the entire stream.”

I just put this site to tell that it's possible to estimate the "overhead" size.

**Note**: **Overhead** is some amount of extra data added into the compressed version of the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the ZIP format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29) ..

Assuming that there is only *one* central directory and *no* comments and *no* extra fields, the overhead should be similar to the following. (The overhead will only go up if any additional metadata is added.)

- Per file (Local file header) - 30+len(filename)
- Per file (Data descriptor) - 12 (to 16)
- Per file (Central directory header) - 46+len(filename)
- Per archive (EOCD) - 22

So the overhead, where `afn` is the average length of all file names, and `f` is the number of files:

```
  f * ((30 + afn) + 12 + (46 * afn)) + 22
= f * (88 + 2 * afn) + 22
```

This of course makes ZIP a *very poor* choice for very tiny bits of compressed data where a (file) structure or metadata is not required - [zlib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlib), on the other hand, is a *very thin* Deflate wrapper.

For small payloads, a poor Deflate implementation may also result in a significantly larger "compressed" size, such as the notorious .NET implementation ..

---

Examples:

- Storing 1 file, with name "hello world note.txt" (len = 20),

  `= 1 * (88 + 2 * 20) + 22 = 150` bytes overhead
- Storing 100 files, with an average name of 14 letters,

  `= 100 * (88 + 2 * 14) + 22 = 11622` bytes overhead

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you please explain more about each bullet parts? For example I don’t know how we could obtain (EOCD) size. And how you compute ‘afn’? Thanks again.

Comment: `afn = (len(filename1)+len(filename2)+len(filename3)+..)/number_of_files`. Going with the other assumptions (e.g. no appending and thus no duplicate CD entries) there is only one EOCD of 22 bytes.

Comment: you mean EOCD always is 22 for all files?   "Data descriptor" and "Local file header" are always  16 and 30 respectively?

Comment: Data descriptor is a fixed size, EOCD (*without* comments) is a fixed size, but the EOCD (*and* Central directory entries) can be duplicated if the ZIP file is "appended" to. The Local file header and the Central director header size both *depend* on the length of the filename (and are thus a variable size, even when *not* using extra comment/field features).

Comment: Thank you again. sorry if I ask many questions. what is "comment/field features".   Is there a good article that explain overhead in detail.

Comment: @user3184352 The additional metadata can be set with the appropriate ZIP tool and can be pretty much whatever data (and whatever length up to 65k/entrry) is desired. WinZIP says [this](http://kb.winzip.com/help/winzip/HELP_COMMENT.htm) about comments: "A comment is optional text information that is embedded in a Zip file. It can be viewed, created, edited, or deleted using the Comment window."